# What is causing this iOS App Crash Report?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, crash-reports, plcrashreporter

I need some help to find out what could be causing this Crash Report. Unfortunately, none of our users that have submitted similar Crash Reports have given us any additional information that will help even pinpoint what they are doing in the app at the time of the crash. Nothing in the report seems to be linked to my code directly (ie it all seems to be built-in Framework calls). I can't simulate this myself, so it's going to be tough to know when/if I have resolved this.

Anyway, here's the Crash Report:

```
Incident Identifier: 4A302435-AF92-4B80-837D-E8161C05FA6B
CrashReporter Key: [TODO]
Hardware Model: iPad2,6
Process: MyApp [213]
Path: /var/mobile/Applications/1065CCF2-93EE-4D8E-A07C-XXXXXEE6XXXX/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier: MyApp
Version: 325
Code Type: ARM
Parent Process: launchd [1]

Date/Time: 2013-10-01 06:24:49 0000
OS Version: iPhone OS 7.0.2 (11A501)
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xb17b688c
Crashed Thread: 0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x399fdb26 objc_msgSend + 6
1 Foundation 0x2fb033a3 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 55
2 Foundation 0x2fb032e7 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 207
3 Foundation 0x2fb03201 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 61
4 CFNetwork 0x2ee36ed3 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 75
5 CFNetwork 0x2ee35ae3 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 55
6 CFNetwork 0x2ee6731f ___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 19
7 CoreFoundation 0x2f0fd719 CFArrayApplyFunction + 37
8 CFNetwork 0x2edcdc3d RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 165
9 CFNetwork 0x2edcdb0d MultiplexerSource::perform() + 221
10 CFNetwork 0x2edcd9a1 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 49
11 CoreFoundation 0x2f19518b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
12 CoreFoundation 0x2f19465b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 207
13 CoreFoundation 0x2f192e4f __CFRunLoopRun + 623
14 CoreFoundation 0x2f0fdce7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 523
15 CoreFoundation 0x2f0fdacb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 107
16 GraphicsServices 0x33df8283 GSEventRunModal + 139
17 UIKit 0x3199fa41 _UIApplicationMain 1137
18 MyApp 0x0016a60f _main 187
```

Comment: try to take the help of Breakpoints and debug it .

Comment: all this crash report shows, is meta data of the device/crash and then the stack call, which it doesn't show any view controllers, but it is using NSURLConnection which is used to download stuff, so if you did not put in any code for this then it might be a 3rd party framework, if you are i would break point before you make any request calls and see if those break, it also looks like it's calling a block, so maybe on the returning end of the request... but i would ignore that and check anywhere you make a request via URLConnection

Comment: It's crashing on some block call - probably you have asynchronous operation which calls a delegate which can be deallocated before block finishes (for example when user change view before network operation has finished).

Comment: @Dino Mic did you used the PLCrashReport lib to extract all those above data. please share code. how you have extracted the line numbers, the method and class where the app crashed.